# resposive web design for drupal 6 themes

Tags: drupal, responsive-design

I have a big website build in drupal and i am using zen TSI theme. It currently doesnt have a responsive web design using CSS3 .I want to build this responsive web design using CSS3  to all my pages  how do i do it .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a responsive design, You need to use HTML5 to design the webpage with proper use of CSS keeping in mind the Fluid context.
You can refer [this](http://johnflower.org/blog/responsive-web-design-drupal).

Comment: so i have change  each and every css file is there a generalized way to it because  there are many pages in my website

Comment: Changing all the CSS Design is the only generalized way since you are designing from scratch.
Other option is to start from responsive theme and customize it according to the need.